# Free C# Grid/Graph component

Tags: c#, .net, graphing

Can anyone recommend a free grid/graphing component for C#/.NET?  I'm having a look at NPlot right now, but so far I'm finding it quite troublesome.

EDIT: I particularly need something that plugs into Windows Forms - I'm not doing ASP.NET, and don't really fancy reproducing my graph using Google's API every time I get a new data point (several times a second).

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

MS just [released](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt) one if you are using 3.5 or you could use [ZedGraph](https://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/)

EDIT: The Link is Just a ASP.NET demo they have a [Windows Forms Release](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14422) as well with [DEMOS](https://web.archive.org/web/20190502114248/https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart)

**Microsofts Chart Control**

[image: Microsofts Chart Control]

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at ZedGraph.  The MS one appears to only be for ASP.NET web stuff, whilst I need Windows Forms.

Comment: No the link I sent you is for an ASP.NET demo but they will work for Windows forms as well

Comment: Ah, thanks!  Have installed ZedGraph and playing around with it now.  If I can get my own graph to come up, it's won :-)

Answer (score 3):

[MS Chart Controls](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyId=130f7986-bf49-4fe5-9ca8-910ae6ea442c&displayLang=en) ([VS tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=1d69ce13-e1e5-4315-825c-f14d33a303e9&displaylang=en)) work with winforms too:

> Microsoft Chart Controls for Microsoft
>   .NET Framework 3.5 will install new
>   assemblies that contain the ASP.NET
>   and Windows Forms Chart Controls.

I haven't had time to use it yet, so I don't know whether it supports charting/plotting (rather than data-graphing).

Comment: Thanks Marc.  I've gone with ZedGraph for now, seems pretty good!

Answer (score 3):

I can highly recommend ZedGraph (http://zedgraph.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page). It was very easy to configure from my experience (and well documented), not to mention that it seems really quite versatile.

Comment: Agreed - I got a graph up and running in 20 minutes or so, including download time.

Answer (score 1):

Zedgraph seems to be a good tool to plot 2d lines anc histograms. Is there a c# library which allow to visualize 2D data (f[x,y]) as the matlab function pcolor or imagesc ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Dynamic Data Display](http://www.codeplex.com/dynamicdatadisplay) on CodePlex. It's a pretty rich library for WPF with good documentation and good sample code.